# How to perform conditional dataframe operations?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given df

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2, 1, 2], [2, 4, 4, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1, 2], [4, 2, 2, 3, 0], 
              [5, 1, 4, 3, -4], [1, 5, 2, 3, -20], [2, 4, 4, 2, 0], [3, 3, 1, 2, -1], 
              [4, 2, 2, 2, 0], [5, 1, 4, 2, -2]],
             columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
             index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

How can I create a column `'f'`, that corresponds to the last value in column `'e'` before a change in value in column `'d'`, and holds that value until the next change in value in column `'d'` the output would be:

```
    a   b   c   d   e    f
1   1   5   2   1   2    nan
2   2   4   4   1   2    nan
3   3   3   1   1   2    nan
4   4   2   2   3   0     2
5   5   1   4   3   -4    2
6   1   5   2   3   -20   2
7   2   4   4   2   0    -20
8   3   3   1   2   -1   -20
9   4   2   2   2   0    -20
10  5   1   4   2   -2   -20
```

**Edit:** `@Noobie` presented a solution that when applied in real data, it breaks down when there's a smaller than previous value in column `'d'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we should offer better native support for dealing with contiguous groups, but until then you can us the compare-cumsum-groupby pattern:

```
g = (A["d"] != A["d"].shift()).cumsum()
A["f"] = A["e"].groupby(g).last().shift().loc[g].values
```

which gives me

```
In [41]: A
Out[41]: 
    a  b  c  d   e     f
1   1  5  2  1   2   NaN
2   2  4  4  1   2   NaN
3   3  3  1  1   2   NaN
4   4  2  2  2   0   2.0
5   5  1  4  2  -4   2.0
6   1  5  2  2 -20   2.0
7   2  4  4  3   0 -20.0
8   3  3  1  3  -1 -20.0
9   4  2  2  3   0 -20.0
10  5  1  4  3  -2 -20.0
```

---

This works because `g` is a count corresponding to each contiguous group of `d` values.  Note that in this case, using the example you posted, g is the same as column "d", but that needn't be the case.  Once we have `g`, we can use it to group column `e`:

```
In [55]: A["e"].groupby(g).last()
Out[55]: 
d
1     2
2   -20
3    -2
Name: e, dtype: int64
```

and then

```
In [57]: A["e"].groupby(g).last().shift()
Out[57]: 
d
1     NaN
2     2.0
3   -20.0
Name: e, dtype: float64

In [58]: A["e"].groupby(g).last().shift().loc[g]
Out[58]: 
d
1     NaN
1     NaN
1     NaN
2     2.0
2     2.0
2     2.0
3   -20.0
3   -20.0
3   -20.0
3   -20.0
Name: e, dtype: float64
```

Comment: amazing, very educational. Thanks!!

Comment: actually this is a good point. @DSM can u create a new issue about this (there is an old one i'll link to); with a nice example and if possible an API that you would like to see

Comment: @DSM its a nice solution but arent you using too much refinement with the `.loc[g]` at the end? I mean, my two liner would work as well provided the same column g. its just more intuitive IMHO

Answer (score 1):

easy my friend. unleash the `POWER OF PANDAS` !

```
A.sort_values(by = 'd', inplace = True)
A['lag'] = A.e.shift(1)
A['output'] = A.groupby('d').lag.transform(lambda x : x.iloc[0])

A
Out[57]: 
    a  b  c  d   e   lag  output
1   1  5  2  1   2   NaN     NaN
2   2  4  4  1   2   2.0     NaN
3   3  3  1  1   2   2.0     NaN
4   4  2  2  2   0   2.0     2.0
5   5  1  4  2  -4   0.0     2.0
6   1  5  2  2 -20  -4.0     2.0
7   2  4  4  3   0 -20.0   -20.0
8   3  3  1  3  -1   0.0   -20.0
9   4  2  2  3   0  -1.0   -20.0
10  5  1  4  3  -2   0.0   -20.0
```

Comment: your answer is correct...for the dummy example. But when I apply it to my real data, something seems to break down :(. starts giving good results then it gives bogus data

Comment: I know the issue, it works only if the numbers in d are ascending

Comment: just sort the values in the correct order before using that solution, bro

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you incorporate it in your answer please?

Comment: thanks for your effort. Your approach didn't work. I think Mr. DSM understands the issue very well.

Comment: well @dsm is a big boss for sure. but my solution works in your example. the only thing to blame here is the inaccuracy of your example my man